# Running MMU-less Linux on ARM Cortex-R4

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, filesystems, embedded-linux

I'm using ARM Cortex-R4 for my system. It has a Memory Protection Unit instead of a Memory Management Unit. Effectively, this means that there's dedicated hardware for memory protection but that there's a one-to-one mapping between physical and virtual addresses. I'm a little confused about which Linux I should go for - standard Linux kernel with MMU disabled or uCLinux.

On ARM's evaluation board, I have run the standard kernel compiled with MMU disabled. I used the cramfs filesystem which is available on the official ARM website. After the kernel boots up, I'm in the shell, but I couldn't do much experimentation as I found that, most of the time, the shell stops responding (particularly when I press "tab" for auto-completion).

So I'm still not sure whether the MMU-less kernel should run smoothly if I use the correct filesystem. Also, which distro (buildroot?) should I use for the no-VM Linux?

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out what exactly is crashing and why, rather than speculating that it is the kernel or the filesystem.  If you can get a second path into the board - say both uart and network, that would help, as you can see if one remains alive even when the other hangs.  You could also do something like have a userspace daemon write to the terminal (or even a kernel module printk) periodically to say "still here" - at least that would help you determine if your shell is hanging while the rest of the system runs, or if the kernel is hanging. Or in response to a gpio button...

Comment: The printk() suggestion is probably better than a user-space process.  Running in Real = Virtual mode is challenging, at best.  My vote is for uCLinux.

Answer (score 9):

It's been more than 2 years since I asked this question. Now is the time I should write what I found for myself.

ucLinux was a project forked from the Linux kernel long back with the aim to develop Kernel for MMU less systems. However, after a certain while, it was merged to the parent Linux branch. So, today there doesn't exist any active ucLinux distribution.

So, if you disable MMU from the mainline kernel configuration, you'll get an MMU-less version. In fact, now there are configuration options provided in the kernel itself whereby a user can specify the memory layout and the access permissions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

uClinux is a Linux distribution which uses the Linux kernel with the MMU "turned off" and adds some applications and libraries on top of it. You wont choose one or the either as they are best one on top of the other.

If you got to a point where you have a shell running, you've managed to boot Linux sans MMU on your board but ran into a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ucLinux was built for something just like this [mmu less systems]
http://www.uclinux.org/description/